# DynamoDB Perl Abstraction

Tags: database, perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I recently read about Amazon's new DB offering, DynamoDB, and must admit it sounds very compelling. However, before I run off and start re-programming my Model layer to take advantage of the new kid on the block I need some more specifics. Does anyone know of a Perl package that abstracts the DynamoDB or is that too soon? I would call it an 'ORM' package, but there are no relationships in the DynamoDB world. Is there one in alpha, beta? How can I access amazon's dynamodb via Perl?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it's *too soon*.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use my perl module Net::Amazon::DynamoDB (@MadHacker: i took the liberty to adapt your signing code above).

- CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=net%3A%3Aamazon%3A%3Adynamodb
- Latest always on github: https://github.com/ukautz/Net-Amazon-DynamoDB

Comment: looks like a DBD module could be made of that

Answer (score 0):

I wrote interface for DynamoDB in JavaScript
I am also Perl programmer
Please look at example provided, it's very similar to Perl

[See example and download link here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85588&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it using perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Net::Amazon::AWSSign;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

use LWP::UserAgent;

use HTTP::Request::Common;
use DateTime::Format::HTTP;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256 hmac_sha256_base64);
use URI::Escape;

my $iam_key_id = 'Your AWS Access Key';
my $iam_secret = 'Your Security tocken';

my $url = "https://sts.amazonaws.com/?" .
"Action=GetSessionToken" .
"&Version=2011-06-15";

my $awsSign = new Net::Amazon::AWSSign("$iam_key_id", "$iam_secret"); # New object
my $awsSignedRESTURI = $awsSign->addRESTSecret($url); # Returns signed REST query URI for lwp-get, curl, etc.

my $response = `curl -s "$awsSignedRESTURI"`;
print Dumper($response);

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $response);
$xp->set_namespace('xx','https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/');   
my $sessionToken = $xp->getNodeText('/xx:GetSessionTokenResponse/GetSessionTokenResult/Credentials/SessionToken');
my $accessKeyId = $xp->getNodeText('/xx:GetSessionTokenResponse/GetSessionTokenResult/Credentials/AccessKeyId');
my $secretAccessKey = $xp->getNodeText('/xx:GetSessionTokenResponse/GetSessionTokenResult/Credentials/SecretAccessKey');
print $sessionToken . "\n";

#   SESSION TOKEN RECEIVED

put('{"TableName":"Test","Item":{"Id":{"S":"1"},"name":{"S":"somedata"}}}');
print "-----------------------------\n";
get('{"TableName":"Test","Key":{"HashKeyElement":{"S":"1"}}}');

exit;


sub get
{
  my ($json) = @_;

  perform('GetItem', $json);
}

sub put
{
  my ($json) = @_;

  perform('PutItem', $json);
}

sub perform
{
  my ($target, $json) = @_;

  my $class = 'DateTime::Format::HTTP';
  my $date = $class->format_datetime(DateTime->now);

  my $tosign =
    "POST\n" .
    "/\n" .
    "\n" .
    "host:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\n" .
    "x-amz-date:$date\n" .
    "x-amz-security-token:" . $sessionToken . "\n" .
    "x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20111205.$target\n" .
    "\n" .
    $json;

  my $b64 = hmac_sha256_base64(sha256($tosign), $secretAccessKey);
  while (length($b64) % 4) {$b64 .= '=';}

  ##Dynamo request
  my $string =
    "POST http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1\n" .
    "host: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\n" .
    "x-amz-date: $date\n" .
    "x-amzn-authorization: AWS3 AWSAccessKeyId=" . $accessKeyId . ",Algorithm=HmacSHA256,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target,Signature=$b64\n" .
    "x-amz-target: DynamoDB_20111205.$target\n" .
    "x-amz-security-token: " . $sessionToken . "\n" .
    "content-type: application/x-amz-json-1.0\n" .
    "connection: Keep-Alive\n" .
    "user-agent: perl\n" .
    "\n" .
    $json;

  my $req = HTTP::Request->parse($string);

  my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;

  print Dumper($ua->request($req));
}
```

Comment: Funny, the first portion of this example is from my code I added to a thread on the AWS forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314685#314685. :-) But thanks anyway. I am already at work on this and have a few packages under development already based on the code you just posted.

Comment: I should thank you then. I got the code from your post and figured out the rest and had it working end to end. I posted the answer, thinking it might be helpful for someone looking for a solution.

Comment: Interesting stuff.  Looking forward to using a package that hides these details!  Looks like Amazon is at least trying to have some security around this while not throwing out security.